# How do I export goods if there's a factory consuming them?

Tags: tropico-4

I have a few missions that need me to export pineapples and fish, but I have a cannery that takes them in to produced canned food.  How do I fulfill those requests?

Comment: Fire everyone at the cannery and close those positions?

Comment: eww, that's not a good idea since I rely on them for my primary source of income :(

Comment: Ok then how about you increase pineapple and fish production to the point where the cannery can't keep up?

Comment: not possible, seems like they have an unlimited storage capacity, or at least exceedingly high.  I've already pretty much saturated my island with all possible good locations for fish and pineapple and my cannery's out pacing them.

Comment: Shift income to another export while you shut down the cannery?

Comment: I'm in the process of trying that.  Hopefully the storage will fill up and then stuff will start being exported.

Comment: it turns out the quest has time limits and mine expired before I could get around to it, oh well, the question is still open

Comment: Personally, I think all the suggestions I gave are plausible so what answer are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I'm with John on this one, temporarily fire workers at the cannery. Sometimes it's a difficult balance keeping cash going and doing the quests :)

Comment: @John if you can back your suggestions up with proof, put it in an answer and I'll accept them since I was never able to confirm due to the quest ending before I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I don't know how I would *prove* that it was the *raw* resource not the *processed* resource being exported if I tried to outpace the factory, so I'll just suggest the most obvious solution.

Shut down the factory.  It may be painful, but you should be able to shift income to other exports for a while.

[image]

As you can see, the factory has produced nothing in at least 1 year, and I'm still successfully exporting Tobacco.  $11,822 worth, to be exact.

Comment: To prove it, get a quest to export tobacco and try to fulfill it while you have a cigar factory built, but shut down.  See if it works.

Comment: @yx_ It works.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

To export pineapple create a cannery next to the pineapple farms as well as build a teamstars office next to the cannery.

Comment: The question is to export *pineapple* instead of *canned pineapple*. They're trying *not* to can the pineapples. (Or rather, to can something else instead of pineapples.)

Answer (score 1):

you can fire all of the workers in the factory which spends the resources you want to export

Comment: Did you have any source for this? or it's just experience. If is self-experience is not a problem, just wondering if there are SS, videos or links.